# Is the expression "for all time" correct?

Tags: time

I'd like to know what's the correct usage of the expression "for all time".
In particular in this sentence: "she cried for all time" (it's about a girl who took a plane and cried during the whole flight).
Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: "for all time" means "until the end of time". You want "she cried all the time [that she was on the plane]". You may be interested in [ell.se] for this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

"For all time" means "forever", and is used with a certain dramatic flair.

> Shakespeare's genius is not just for the 17th century, it is for all time.

Or,

> God is not the God of the Bible only, he is God for all time.

The situation you are using is more bounded. You might say:

> She cried the whole flight. *or* She cried for the whole flight.

Pity the poor girl were she to cry for all time. That sounds like a Greek tragedy to me.